# Include managed C# DLL into unmanaged C++ DLL - all in one single file

Tags: c++, .net, command-line, unmanaged, dllexport

Intro : [How do I combine an unmanaged dll and a managed assembly into one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721271/how-do-i-combine-an-unmanaged-dll-and-a-managed-assembly-into-one-file)

> In comparison to the question above i need to combine DLLs so that
>   final mixed DLL could export their functions to other unmanaged
>   applications.

For this i would like to compile them both as .netmodule and then combine them into one file with a linker so i have :

1) Libs - project with some library in C# - it does not have any dependencies and and i can easily compile it like a .netmodule

2) Links - C++ unmanaged project that has reference to C# library and unfortunately i am not able to build it with cl.exe compiler because it always gives an error saying that namespace from C# library cannot be found even though i tried to point compiler to all folders where it can find reference to my C# assembly, this C++ project is used like a simple C++ wrapper over CLR methods from C#

Here is my batch script and second line throws an error :

```
"c:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/csc.exe" /target:module /out:./Build/libs.netmodule Libs\Properties\*.cs Libs\*.cs
"c:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" /clr /AI"D:\T\CPlus\Library\Release" /AI"D:\T\CPlus\Library\Libs" /AI"D:\T\CPlus\Library\Libs\Properties" /LN Links\*.cpp
```

**Question** : does anybody now how to let C++ know where it can find C# assembly to resolve the reference or maybe i need to somehow explicitly mention my header files in batch commands?

**Source code :** C# is just empty class with method Foo and C++ looks like this one.

```
// Links.h

#pragma once

#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

using namespace System;
using namespace Libs; // cl.exe cannot resolve this reference

// Links.cpp

#include "Links.h"

DllExport int __stdcall Execute()
{
    Libs::CLibrary::Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final working version.

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /target:module /out:Libs.netmodule /recurse:..\Libs\*.cs
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" /clr /LN /Fo /Y- /Z7 /FU Libs.netmodule ..\Links\Links.cpp /link /LIBPATH:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib"
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\link.exe" /DLL /LTCG /CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW /OUT:Library.dll Libs.netmodule Links.obj /LIBPATH:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib"
```

Useful links :

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83218913-56df-4530-9d6c-45076bdc0acb/how-to-merge-several-managed-and-unmanaged-dlls-into-a-single-dll?forum=vcgeneral
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0082757-b179-4cce-9c6e-847f39cfefa4/cannot-find-referenced-assemblyproject-from-clr-project?forum=msbuild
- [How to link C# and C++ assemblies into a single executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609056/how-to-link-c-sharp-and-c-assemblies-into-a-single-executable)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6ds95cz0.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx

Now i am able to use exported functions from .NET in unmanaged applications. Moreover, all information from both projects - Links (C++) and Libs (C#) - was grouped in one file - Library.dll. This way i can merge into one DLL as many projects as i want and it does not matter whether they are managed or native.